# I want to freeze an object on pressing a key in unity3d c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So what I want to do is when a player presses a key the object somehow deletes the rigidbody or just freezes it. I looked at the docs but I didn't understand what to look for.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
{

}
```

Also I want the player to be able to unfreeze it after he froze it. (or recover the rigidbody when it was deleted)

Comment: Can you define "Freeze"?

Comment: Like when a player presses a button all the axis stop changing. Rotation stops, movement stops and things like that

Comment: So, you can consider it as a state of the object, in which it blocks all position manipulation.

Comment: Yeah. Also it would be good if it can recover later to be able to move around

Comment: Are you able to detect to which object the freeze applies?

Comment: Well how is the object moving? If it is e.g. a Rigidbody you can set `isKinematic` or simply set the velocity to `0`. If you move it with some input .. well then ignore all input while it is frozen .. If you want to freeze everything you can use `Time.timeScale = 0` but this has some side effects so totally depends on further information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said what you want is do freeze the Rigidbody like e.g.

```
private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
private float velocity;

private void Awake ()
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponemt<Rigidbody>();
}

private bool isFrozen;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        isFrozen = !isFrozen;
        if(isFrozen) velocity = _rigidbody.velocity;
        _rigidbody.velocity = isFrozen ? Vector3.zero : velocity;
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = isFrozen;
    }
}
```

and when you want it to react to physics again disable `isKinematic` and assign back the `velocity`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply set 'enabled' to false on the Rigidbody component.

Something like this, note that it would likely make sense to cache the rigidbody on Awake() or whatever fits your context.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: it says that there is no definition of "enabled" to rigidbody. What should i put there or should i add it in an other way?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, please refer to derHugo's reply in that case.